# VB.NET - DataGridView Data not showing

Tags: vb.net

I am working on a WINFORM project. I am trying to get a DataGridView to show correctly, but the only item that shows is the headers. I tried following some internet articles, but I am not able to get the data to show in the grid. I am trying to create 4 columns. The first one is checkbox column and the rest are to display the data (minus the last column, which is supposed to hidden) I can get the data to show if I remove the line: `DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False`. What do I need to get the data to show?

```
Private Sub GetDataRows(ByVal DateList As String)
    Dim SQLConn As New SQLConnector(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("connection").ToString)
    Dim SQLStatement As String = "SELECT [upload_date],[name],[row_id] FROM [dbo].[db_table] WHERE upload_date in (" + DateList + ")"
    Dim dtResults As New DataTable

    dtResults = SQLConn.GetDataTableByStatement(SQLStatement) 'Call database and returns a datatable

    DataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = False

    GenerateGridView()
    DataGridView1.DataSource = dtResults



End Sub
Private Sub GenerateGridView()

    Dim checkColumn As New DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn()
    checkColumn.Name = " "
    checkColumn.HeaderText = " "
    checkColumn.Width = 50
    checkColumn.ReadOnly = False
    checkColumn.FillWeight = 10
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(checkColumn)

    Dim gridCol1 As New DataGridViewColumn
    gridCol1.Name = "upload_date"
    gridCol1.HeaderText = "Upload Date"
    gridCol1.DataPropertyName = "upload_date"
    gridCol1.Width = 50
    gridCol1.ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(gridCol1)

    Dim gridCol2 As New DataGridViewColumn
    gridCol2.Name = "hospital_name"
    gridCol2.HeaderText = "Hospital Name"
    gridCol2.DataPropertyName = "hospital_name"
    gridCol2.Width = 50
    gridCol2.ReadOnly = True
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(gridCol2)

    Dim gridCol3 As New DataGridViewColumn
    gridCol3.Name = "row_id"
    gridCol3.HeaderText = "Row ID"
    gridCol3.DataPropertyName = "row_id"
    gridCol3.Width = 50
    gridCol3.ReadOnly = True
    gridCol3.Visible = False
    DataGridView1.Columns.Add(gridCol3)
End Sub
```

Comment: If you don't want the grid to auto-generate the columns then get rid of that method and create them in the designer. I'm guessing that your specific issue is that you are creating `DataGridViewColumn` objects instead of `DataGridViewTextBoxColumn` objects.

Comment: Why would you use the `New` keyword in `Dim dtResults As New DataTable` if you are just going to assign something else tot hat same variable on the very next line? Why would you not just use one line: `Dim dtResults As DataTable = SQLConn.GetDataTableByStatement(SQLStatement)`?

Answer (score 0):

Auto generate column is false, May be it is creating problem. Why won't you try it in form design.
Follow the steps:
design form view -> data Source -> Select your data source -> select the table you wanna show on data grid -> click on it -> you will found the option of grid view -> click on it -> then drag the table to your form.
you don't need to set data source as well.
but if u wanna hide any column you have to do that manually.
hope it works.